# What is the purpose of THC for a Cannabis plant?

Tags: botany

Why does a Cannabis plant produce THC? This question is brought up drawing an analogy to nicotine in tobacco, where nicotine is developed by tobacco plants as a pesticide. Is THC a pesticide as well? I'm imagining that marijuana plants don't have rheumatoid arthritis.

Comment: It may also act as an insulation barrier for the plant to protect it from the cold.

Comment: Phytocannabinoids are found in an exceedingly wide range of plants, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it is used by Cannabis sativa as a type of sunscreen as it absorbs UV light
https://www.reddit.com/r/trees/comments/2v79dv/science_sunday_13_wait_why_does_cannabis_have_thc/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahydrocannabinol